# Find all combinations without repetition

Tags: c++, combinations

I have to find all combinations using 3 integers without repetition in C++ application.

I can calculate how many combination there are going to be when I specify how many integers do I have.

```
unsigned int combinations(unsigned int n){
    return ((n/3) * ((n-1)/2) * (n-2));
}
```

But how can I add to `vector` those all combinations? f.e using: `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`: `123`,`234`,`124`, `134`. The order is not important and `123` is same as `321`.

Comment: using std::vector<T>::push_back(...) function?

Comment: But how can I calculate those: `123`,`234`,`124`,`134`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct tuple3 {
    int a, b, c;   
    tuple3(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
};

vector<tuple3> combinations3(vector<int> n) {
    vector<tuple3> ret;
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator it1 = n.begin(); it1 < n.end(); it1++) {
        for(vector<int>::const_iterator it2 = n.begin(); it2 < it1; it2++) {
            for(vector<int>::const_iterator it3 = n.begin(); it3 < it2; it3++) {
                ret.push_back(tuple3(*it1, *it2, *it3));
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To future readers: Use C++11 `std::array` or `std::tuple` if you can. I did not here because it is not yet available or default on many compilers.

Comment: Thanks for this code, however it calculates all combinations also in another order(with repetition). Check my first post: f.e using: `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`: `123`,`234`,`124`, `134`. The order is not important and `123` is same as `321`.

Comment: Also, in second for: I think it should be `it2++` instead of `it1++`